# ME-1 personal monitor showing signal on meter but no sound on outputs

Tags: untagged

We have a personal monitoring system based on a ME-U receiving Dante from an M7CL, and several ME-1 personal mixers. Since Christmas day, the mixers have not been functioning correctly - they are showing signal on their meters, but there is no output on the headphone socket. We've tried 3-4 ME-1s, they are all exhibiting the same behaviour. The "Local Mic" function is working, so there is no problem with the headphones or connection.

[One answer on a forum](https://community.allen-heath.com/forums/topic/no-sound-out-on-the-me-1-but-i-get-sound-out-of-avioms-on-same-cable) suggested that we should check the clock frequency is at 48kHz because the ME-1s can't do 44.1, and will not report an error when fed 44.1, they will exhibit this highly broken of signal on the display but no audio, but I don't think this is the problem, we are using 48kHz on the M7CL, and I can't see anywhere else where it could be set.

I have been able to record from the Dante network using my Laptop and Dante virtual sound card, and have checked all the connections in Dante controller, but I'm sure the problem can't be on the Dante side as I am getting signal showing on the meters of the ME-1, just nothing from the audio out.

Comment: So something has evidently changed and with the fact that you have tried multiple ME-1's it's more likely to be at the M7CL. Have you tried checking the DANTE Routing between the M7CL and the rest of the gear? Also check that the master clock setting is correct.

Comment: Have you got a PC with Dante Controller plugged on an output port of the ME-U to check if any errors appear on the Dante side ?

Comment: As far as I'm concerned if the ME-1 is showing a signal on it's meters, but not sending it out of it's headphone socket, there is a major firmware bug in the ME-1, but I agree something must have changed at the M7CL or ME-U. I've checked everything in Dante controller, and tried recording with Dante virtual Soundcard using Ableton Live, which worked fine. I've updated the answer with my progress.

Comment: I suppose I should suggest you "kick it all in the guts" (power cycle) to at least see whether this resets something at a fundamental level in the m7cl, then if this doesn't do anything, start some elimination tests to troubleshoot what is introducing the error.

Comment: So one of my colleagues was able to get it working again. They turned a few things off and on, changed some settings and changed them back, and it's worked ever since. They don't really know what they did.